# Stuck on constructing my semi direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to work out $H \rtimes Q$, where $H = C_{17}$ and $Q = C_{2}$. What this means is that I want to work out the groups that map $\theta: C_2 \rightarrow Aut(C_{17})$.

$Aut(C_{17}) \cong C_{16}$. I know that 2 divides 16 and from here I get two SDP's. One is the direct product, $C_{17} \times C_2$ and the other is the SDP I have to find. What I have said is this:

If we denote $H = \langle a | a^{17} = 1 \rangle, Q = \langle b | b^2 = 1 \rangle$ and $Aut(C_{17}) = \langle \mu | \mu^{16} = 1 \rangle$, then I want to find some $\mu \in Aut(C_{17})$ which will map elements of order $2$ in $Aut(H)$ to elements of order $2$ in $H$, i.e some

$$\mu \in Aut(C_{17}) \mathrm{\, such \, that\, } \mu : a \mapsto a^k \mathrm{\,goes \, to\,} \mu^{2} : a \mapsto a^{k^2} $$

In other words, I want the $k$'s such that $k^2 \equiv 1 \mod 17$. Is this right so far? I'm stuck on how I go about trying to answer the question now.

Comment: Hint: Since the automorphism group of $C_{17}$ is cyclic, there is only one automorphism of order $2$. In order to figure out what it is, I will tell you that for any abelian group, there is an automorphism which works in the exact same way as this one.

Comment: @peoplepower I get that there is one element of order 2, $a^{8}$, but I don't see how this relates to the automorphisms, or does it? Unless that 8 has something to do with my $k$'s?

Comment: Unless its something like: Obviously both $C_{17}$ and $C_2$ are abelian, and as I have worked out one automorphism to be the direct product, is the other one also a type of direct product, i.e multiplication of the eleements? As both these automorphisms work in the samy way

Comment: there is only one nontrivial map $C_2\to \text{Aut}(C_{17})\cong C_{16}$ (since there is only one subgroup of order two).  every abelian group has at least one automorphism of order two: inversion.

Comment: @yoyo Yeah I got that, thats what I did in my working out, but I don't get how to work out what this automorphism is

Comment: if $C_2=\langle x|x^2=1\rangle$ and $C_{17}=\langle y|y^{17}=1\rangle$ then $xax=a^{-1}$.  the semi-direct product is a dihedral group

Comment: Where do you get that from? Why is it $a^{-1}$ and not $a^2$? Also, how do you know its a dihedral group by just looking at that?

Comment: in any abelian group you have the automorphism $x\mapsto-x$ which is either trivial or of order two

Comment: So I always say that $x \mapsto -x$ is I am working out the automorphism with order 2? If it was greater than 2, then would I use that $n^k$ method, where $n$ is the order of the group?

Comment: @Kaish, in the comments to my answer in your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271774/two-questions-on-calculating-semi-direct-products/271788#271788 , I already told you about the automorphism of order 2 in a cyclic group's automorphism group: the inversion $\,a\to a^{-1}\,$ ... As was already said to you by other members, you may seem to be trying to deal with SDP without first having understood way more basic and elementary stuff, and this is making, and will continue to make, things rather hard to you in group theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had assumed previously that you knew what an automorphism group is.  Perhaps you need some elaboration on this.  I'm going to go through this particular example step by step as thoroughly as I can.

$\text{Aut}(C_{17})$ is a cyclic group of order $16$, but it is not $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ (just isomorphic to it).  It is generated by the bijective homomorphism $\alpha:C_{17}\rightarrow C_{17}$ defined by $\alpha(x)=x^3$.  So $\alpha^2$ is the map $x\mapsto x^{3^2}$, $\alpha^3$ is the map $x\mapsto x^{3^3}$, etc.  Because of number theory stuff, $\alpha^{16}$ is the map $x\mapsto x$, which is the identity homomorphism $\text{id}$ on $C_{17}$, and no other $\alpha^{i}$ is the identity for $i\leq 15$.  So $$\text{Aut}(C_{17})=\{\text{id},\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots, \alpha^{15}\}.$$
We want to find a homomorphism $\theta:C_2\rightarrow \text{Aut}(C_{17})$ to define the semidirect product.  You already found that the homomorphism $\theta_1:C_2\rightarrow \text{Aut}(C_{17})$ defined by $\theta_1(x)=\text{id}$ yields $C_{17}\rtimes_{\theta_1}C_2=C_{17}\times C_2$. This is one of the two possible semidirect products. We find the other one by noticing that the order of $a$ (the generator of $C_2$) is $2$, so it needs to map to the automorphism $\alpha^8$, because $(\alpha^8)^2=\alpha^{16}=\text{id}$. So let $\theta:C_2\rightarrow \text{Aut}(C_{17})$ be defined by $\theta(a)=\alpha^8$.

Remember that $x^3$ means $3x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$, since the operation is addition.  The relation to DonAntonio's comment is that $x^{3^8}$ means $3^8x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$.  But $3^8\equiv 16 \pmod{17}$, i.e. $3^8\equiv -1 \pmod{17}$.  So the map $\alpha^8$ is the map $x\mapsto -x$.

You asked in the comments if you should always use $x\mapsto -x$ for an automorphism of order $2$.  The answer is no, because it is not true in general that this map is a homomorphism.  In fact, it is if and only if the group is abelian.  You should prove this real quick.  (*Hint*: Let $\phi:x\mapsto x^{-1}$. $b^{-1}a^{-1}=\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.)  So only with abelian groups can you use this as an automorphism of order $2$ (though it may not be the *only* automorphism of order $2$).

So what does this mean for your semidirect product $C_{17}\rtimes_{\theta} C_2$?

We proved yesterday that $ba=a\theta(a^{-1})(b)$.  In $C_2$ $a=a^{-1}$, so $ba=a\theta(a)(b)$.  As we determined above, $\theta$ maps $a$ to the automorphism $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, so $\theta(a)(b)=b^{-1}$, so $ba=ab^{-1}$.  We can rewrite that as $b^a=b^{-1}$, yielding the familiar group presentation $$C_{17}\rtimes_{\theta} C_2=\langle a,b|a^2,b^{17},b^a=b^{-1}\rangle$$ which we recognize as the dihedral group $D_{17}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this. I'm slowly working through it, my first question (and hopefully last) is this: Why is the homomorphism $\alpha :C_{17} \rightarrow C_{17}$ definined by $\alpha(x) = x^3$. Where do you get the cubed from? Why not 2 or 5 or anything else?

Comment: Also, After getting $3^8 \equiv -1 \mod 17$, from here you get that $x \rightarrow -x$. Let's say that you got $3^k \equiv 3 \mod 17$, (or whatever, even if it isn't $\mod 17$), then would your $\theta$ map $\alpha^k: x \rightarrow 3x$?

Comment: We pick $3$ because we want a number whose multiplicative order modulo $17$ is $16$.  There is no general way to show you how to determine the generator of $\text{Aut}(C_p)$ (this is an open problem), but in small examples it shouldn't be too hard to just compute $2^i\mod{17}$ until you find that $2^8\equiv 1\pmod{17}$ (meaning that $2$ has multiplicative order $8$, not $16$, and thus is not a generator), then move onto $3$ and compute $3^i\mod{17}$ until you know that the smallest $i$ for which $3^i\equiv 1 \pmod{17}$ is $i=16$.

Comment: Second question: yes it would.

Comment: The important thing in this example, though, isn't what the $d$ in $\alpha:x\mapsto x^d$ is, only that $\alpha$ is a generator of the automorphism group.  Any time $\alpha$ is the generator of the automorphism group of $C_p$, you will have that $\alpha^{p-1}:x\mapsto x^{-1}$.  In fact, if you were doing this example on a test, you could probably just say "let $\alpha$ generate $\text{Aut}(17)$" and proceed from there.  It doesn't actually matter which generator you choose - actually $3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 14$ would all work.

Comment: Hmm... Ok. That makes sense.

I'm working through another example now and I was planning on positing that thread up once I've finished (and hopefully not got stuck). Will you still be online?

Comment: I may well be!  If not I'm sure somebody else will help you out :)

Comment: Oh, slight revision to my 2nd to last comment: should be $\alpha^{(p-1)/2}$.

Comment: The $d$ is important isn't it because that's why you raise to the power $k$ to find out your $m$ such that $d^k \equiv m \mod 17$ (17 is just an example) and then you can say that your alpha maps $x \mapsto mx$ and this gives you your value for $\theta(a^{-1})(b)$, right?

Comment: Also, the $i$, which is also $k$ in my comment just now, I'm assuming that is supposed to be $\geq 1$?

Comment: If all we want is to find $C_p\rtimes C_2$, then we need to inject our $C_2=\langle a \rangle$ into $\text{Aut}(C_p)$.  If we just take $\alpha$ to be an arbitrary generator of $\text{Aut}(C_p)$, we know that $\alpha^{(p-1)/2}$ is the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.  Obviously this map is of order $2$, so we can choose $\theta$ to map $a$ to $\alpha^{(p-1)/2}$.  Then we have that $\theta(a)(b)=b^{-1}$.  The only purpose that the $d$ serves is to show that $\alpha$ generates $\text{Aut}(C_p)$ - not every $d$ will work, but among those that do, it doesn't matter which you pick.

Comment: The congruences come in because when we raise $\alpha:x\mapsto x^d$ by $k$, we get $\alpha^k:x\mapsto x^{d^k}$.  So we are looking for $d$'s where $d^k\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.  There is no reason to actually find the $d$ though, in my opinion - you should just be able to say "Let $\text{Aut}(C_p)=\langle \alpha \rangle$" and be done with it.  I was only explaining the congruences because your book explicitly gave you the $d$'s.

Comment: Ok, so that means it doesn't play much of a role in this particular example right? The one I'm working is mapping $C_3 \rightarrow C_{28}$, and so as it's not of order 2, then I need to find the $d$? Or because $C_3$ is abelian, I therefore can say that $x \mapsto -x$, from your answer?

Comment: Ah I think I understand where your confusion is.  Say you want to map an element of order $n$ into $\text{Aut}(C_m)$.  If you say, let $\text{Aut}(C_m)=\langle \alpha \rangle$, you have that the order of $\alpha$ (and thus $|\text{Aut}(C_m)|$) is given by the Euler $\varphi$ function (google should have a tutorial on $\varphi$).  In the case of $C_3=\langle a \rangle$ and $C_{28}$, $\varphi(28)=12$.  You have to map $a$ to an element of order $3$.  Try $\theta_1:a\mapsto \alpha^{12*1/3}=\alpha^4$ and $\theta_2:a\mapsto \alpha^{12*2/3}=\alpha^8$.

Comment: If it wanted you to map $C_2$ into $C_{28}$ then you would need $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, but with $C_3$, $a$ isn't of order $2$ so it can't map to that.  So in general to find all semidirect products $C_m\rtimes C_n$, you would need to try $\theta_k:a\mapsto \alpha^{\varphi(m)*k/n}$ for $k=1,\ldots, n$ (assuming that $n\mid \varphi(m)$), yielding $C_m\rtimes_{\theta_k}$ C_n$.

Comment: Right, all this theory has just gone out of the window because I made a mistake in my typing. I'm actually mapping $C_7 \rightarrow C_{28}$, so if $\alpha$ generates $C_{28}$, I want to map an element of order 7 to $\alpha$. Order of $\alpha = \varphi(28) = 12$. I now have 6 elements of order 7, $\alpha^{4,8,12,16,18,20,24}$. Now from here, I can't find any $d$ such that $7^d \equiv 1 \mod 28$ as gcd$(7,28) = 7$. What do I do?

Comment: If you had a nontrivial homomorphism $C_7\rightarrow \text{Aut}(C_{28})$, you'd have to map $C_7$ to some subgroup of order $7$ of $\text{Aut}(C_{28})$.  But $7$ doesn't divide $12=\varphi(28)=|\text{Aut}(C_{28}|$ so the only homomorphism from $C_7\rightarrow C_{28}$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: But the answers say the multiplication rule should be $ba = ab^{16}$? Is this getting too long for comments here? Shall I create a new thread with the question and what I've done and where I've gotten stuck? I double checked and I'm defo supposed to be working out $\theta : C_7 \rightarrow Aut(C_{29}) = C_{28}$.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me lol. I was doing $\theta: C_7 \rightarrow C_{28}$ because I already worked out $\mathrm{Aut}C_{29} \cong C_{28}$

Comment: Actually it would be best if we moved it to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7053/discussion-between-alexander-gruber-and-kaish)